# Meteor release changelog

Tags: meteor

I've tried googling for this one but unfortunately got nothing: is there any changelog for the meteor releases? The History.md in github does not include the changes between the releases, say 1.3-rc.5 and 1.3-rc6.

Are there any means to determine the changes between the releases apart from reading the github commits?

Answer (score 0):

http://pastebin.com/raw/SJT7BXwc

Are these the droids you are looking for?

**Updated

Comment: Thanks, but his page is for the stable 1.2 branch, while I'm looking for the new 1.3 changelog.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant. Let's take the latest meteor version for now, which is 1.3-rc.8. I would like to know what was changed between 1.3-rc.7 and 1.3-rc.8. I would also like to know what was changed between 1.3-rc-6 and 1.3-rc.7 and so on.